# Libgdx Ending level is not working properly

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my game the kid is collecting fruits but if he hits the rock 3 times or time is up before collecting the required points, the kid will jump to the half of the screen then fall down and start fail music then move to game over screen but I have two problems here:

1. when time is up the boy jump to top and continue out of the `screen` not the `bottom and the music` of fail is slow and choppy.
2. when kid hits rock 3 times it start fail music well and jump to the center of screen and fall down out of the `screen from bottom` and this is very good then go to game over screen, but when i go back from `game over screen,`the music of the Play screen is not working:
   here is the code :

   ```
   public boolean Rockhit()
       {
           if(Rocks.isRock) {
               rocknum--;
               Hud.collectorLives(rocknum);
               Rocks.isRock=false;

               if (rocknum == 0)
                   return true;
               else
                   return false;

           }
           else
               Hud.collectorLives(rocknum);
           return false;
       }
    public State getState()
       {
           //Gdx.app.log(Float.toString(b2body.getLinearVelocity().x),"hi");
           if ((Hud.getTime()==0&& Hud.getScore()<(level*30)+50)) {
               Fruits.manager.get("music/Backmusic.ogg", Music.class).stop();
               collectoIsDead=true;
               Filter filter = new Filter();
               filter.maskBits = Fruits.NOTHING_BIT;
               for (Fixture fixture : b2body.getFixtureList())
                   fixture.setFilterData(filter);
               b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 5f), b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
               //b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,-2.5f), b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
               Fruits.manager.get("music/fail.mp3", Sound.class).play();

               return State.DEAD;
           }
           if ( Rockhit()) {
               Fruits.manager.get("music/Backmusic.ogg", Music.class).stop();
               collectoIsDead=true;
               Filter filter = new Filter();
               filter.maskBits = Fruits.NOTHING_BIT;
               for (Fixture fixture : b2body.getFixtureList())
                   fixture.setFilterData(filter);
               b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 5f), b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
               //b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,-2.5f), b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
               Fruits.manager.get("music/fail.mp3", Sound.class).play();

               return State.DEAD;
           }
           if((Hud.getTime()==0&& Hud.getScore()>=(level*30)+50)|| (Hud.getScore()>=(level*30)+50)) {
               Fruits.manager.get("music/Backmusic.ogg", Music.class).stop();
               Fruits.manager.get("music/cheering.mp3", Sound.class).play();
               return State.SUCCESS;
           }
   ```

   this is the code of gameover screen:

   ```
   public class GameOverScreen implements Screen {
       private Viewport viewport;
       private Stage stage;
       private Fruits game;
       private float level;

       public GameOverScreen(Fruits game,float level)
       {
           this.level=level;
           this.game=game;
           viewport=new FitViewport(Fruits.V_WIDTH,Fruits.V_HIEGT,new OrthographicCamera());
           stage=new Stage(viewport,((Fruits) game).batch);
           Label.LabelStyle font = new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE);
           Table table=new Table();
           table.center();
           table.setFillParent(true);//the table will take all the stage

           Label gameOverLabel = new Label("Game Over",font);
           Label playAgainLabel = new Label("Click Here",font);
           table.add(gameOverLabel).expandX();
           table.row();
           table.add(playAgainLabel).expandX().padTop(10f);// make it bellow Game over text by 10 pixels
           stage.addActor(table);

       }


       @Override
       public void render(float delta) {
           if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
               game.setScreen(new Worlds(game,level));
               dispose();
           }
           Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
           Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
           stage.draw();

       }
       @Override
       public void show() {

       }



       @Override
       public void resize(int width, int height) {

       }

       @Override
       public void pause() {

       }

       @Override
       public void resume() {

       }

       @Override
       public void hide() {

       }

       @Override
       public void dispose() {

       }
   }
   ```

   here where I am processing the state of the kid in the play screen:

   ```
   public void render(float delta) {


           Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
           Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
           kid.draw(batch);
          if(gameOver())//24
           {
               gameisover=true;
               globalcounter--;
               Gdx.app.log(Float.toString(globalcounter), "counter");
               if(globalcounter==0) {
                   game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, level));
                   dispose();
               }
           }
           if(gameisover==true) {
               globalcounter--;
               Gdx.app.log(Float.toString(globalcounter), "counter");
               if (globalcounter == 0) {
                   game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, level));
                   dispose();
               }
           }
           if(nextLevel())
           {
               prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("levels");
               String name=prefs.getString("level", " ");
               if(name==" ") {
                   prefs.putString("level", Float.toString(level + 1));
                   prefs.flush();
               }

               else {

                   prefs.putString("level", Float.toString(level+1));
                   prefs.flush();
               }
               game.setScreen(new Celebration(game,level+1));
               dispose();
           }
       }

       public boolean gameOver()//25
       {
           if(player.currentState== Collector.State.DEAD )// will show the game over screen after 3 seconds
           {

               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
       public boolean nextLevel()//25
       {
           if(player.currentState== Collector.State.SUCCESS)// will show the game over screen after 3 seconds
           {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start off with, your structure is flawed. 
Your getState does not just return a state. A lot of things are happening before you return a state. You should really move those things and do them AFTER you have changed state.

I don't see a State.PLAYING? You only have 2 states DEAD and SUCCESS

You stop your background music:

```
Fruits.manager.get("music/Backmusic.ogg", Music.class).stop();
```

But it looks like you never start it again.

Comment: Fruits.manager.get("music/Backmusic.ogg", Music.class).stop(); is starting always when at the constructor of Play screen and it works fine when the condition of time is true but did't start when rock condition is true

Comment: Fruits.manager.get("music/Backmusic.ogg", Music.class).stop(); is starting always when at the constructor of Play screen and it works fine when the condition of time is true but did't start when rock condition is true
 I have State.PLAYING but i did't put it here because it does nothing except change the texture of the kid